# Are connectedness preserving monotone functions continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Does there exist any monotone function $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ which takes connected sets to connected sets without being continuous?

If the answer is "no" then can we extend this result to arbitrary topological space?

Comment: A monotone function can only have jump discontinuities, so if it's discontinuous, its image omits at least one point $c$. Then $\text{im}(f) \cap (-\infty, c)$ and $\text{im}(f)\cap (c, \infty)$ partition $\text{im}(f)$ into two disjoint nonempty (relatively) open subsets.

Comment: We can not extend the result (true or not) to arbitrary well-ordered spaces. Consider $ \mathbb Q$ with its standard order and order topology, and the map $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$, $f(q) = 0$ if $q<0$ and $f(q) = 1$ if $q\geq0$. This function is discontinuous and monotone. It sends connected subsets to connected subsets, because $\mathbb Q$ is totally disconnected and the connected components are singeltons.

Comment: Nice counter-example @N. Beck.

Comment: @N.Beck $\mathbb Q$ is not well-orderded in its standard order.

Comment: @Paul Frost You're right. I confused it with totally ordered. The real line isn't well ordered either.